# about "exec.Command" output in Go language

Tags: go

I am trying to use `exec.Command` output into another function, but it didn't work.
I see many stackoverflow questions but not working. I pasted my code below and point out some comments.

```golang
cmd := "ip r | awk '/^def/{print $3}'"   // to get Gateway IP of computer
out, err := exec.Command("bash","-c",cmd).Output()   // Execute Bash with cmd
if err != nil {
    fmt.Printf("%s", err)
}
output := string(out)
fmt.Println(output)     // Output is 192.168.45.45
adb.Connect(output, 5555)   // I want to adb connect 192.168.45.45, but it is not working
```

Comment: What does "it didn't work" exactly mean?

Comment: @zerkms It should connect with IP. Let me explain, if i try with this `adb.Connect("192.168.45.45",5555)` then it will connect successfully, but `adb.Connect(output,5555)` doesnt connect.

Comment: @tcpcd what do you see when you do `fmt.Printf("%q\n", output)`? Do you see `"192.168.45.45"`? Or is there some extra whitespace? If you see whitespace then use `output := strings.TrimSpace(string(out))`

Comment: it is possible that out is empty since you have not returned the function after the error

Comment: @mkopriva I am getting this output `"192.168.45.45\n"`

Comment: @tcpcd you need to trim the `\n`. `adb.Connect` is unable to parse the string with the new line (whitespace character) there.

Comment: @mkopriva Yah, i didnt see your updated comment. now i tried with `TrimSpace` and output is `"192.168.45.45"` and successfully connected to adb shell. Thank you :)